# How to perform a conditional count in R?

Tags: r

I have a data set that looks like the following:

| Member ID # | Location | Donation Amount | Donation Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 5 Toys | Jan |
| 1 | B | 2 Toys | Jan |
| 2 | A | 6 Toys | Mar |
| 3 | B | 4 Toys | Feb |
| 3 | B | 9 Toys | June |

I want to create a column that will **sum** the number of **locations** that a member donated toys **per period**. An example output would be as follows:

| Member ID # | Location | Donation Amount | Donation Month | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 5 Toys | Jan | 2 |
| 1 | B | 2 Toys | Jan | 2 |
| 2 | A | 6 Toys | Mar | 1 |
| 3 | B | 4 Toys | Feb | 1 |
| 3 | B | 9 Toys | June | 1 |

This output lets me know that Member 1 was the only one to donate toys to two different centers in the same month.

I've tried the following code to accomplish this output:

```
output2 <- output1 %>%
           group_by(`Member ID #`, `Location`, `Donation Amount`, `Donation Month`, 
           .groups='Keep') %>%
           mutate(count = n())
```

But this just counts every single entry and not entries per the conditions I listed above. How can I create a conditional count to accomplish my goal?

Comment: in your group_by remove everything but member id and donation month

Comment: Grouping by *all variables* means that each group has exactly one row. Also, `.groups` is not an option in `group_by`, and where it *is* an argument (e.g., [`summarize`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html)), the recognized values for it are all lower-case, i.e., `"keep"`.

Answer (score 0):

try to do this

```
df %>% 
  group_by(`Member ID #`) %>% 
  summarise(Count = n_distinct(Location))
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use `split()` to split our data by `ID` and, within each `ID`, `Duration_month`. Then determine the `unique` amount of locations per split.

```
out <- lapply(split(df, f = ~ df$ID + df$Donation_month), \(x) {
  cbind(x, no_of_locations = rep(length(unique(x$Location)), times = nrow(x)))
})
df_new <- do.call(rbind, out)
rownames(df_new) <- NULL
```

**Output**

```
> df_new
  ID Location Donation_amount Donation_month no_of_locations
1  3        B          4 Toys            Feb               1
2  1        A          5 Toys            Jan               2
3  1        B          2 Toys            Jan               2
4  3        B          9 Toys           June               1
5  2        A          6 Toys            Mar               1
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,2,3,3), Location = c('A','B','A','B','B'),
                 Donation_amount = paste0(c(5,2,6,4,9),' Toys'),
                 Donation_month = c('Jan','Jan','Mar','Feb','June'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `dplyr::add_count()` function will do this for you:

```r
output1 %>%
  add_count(`Member ID #`, Location)
```

Or, if you really want the groups to be retained:

```r
output1 %>%
  group_by(`Member ID #`, Location) %>%
  mutate(Count = n())
```